# What does mean zhōngxing from ZTE in Chinese?

Tags: names

What does mean zhōngxing from ZTE in Chinese? ZTE is the Chinese company that makes, among others, modems, routers, smartphones, etc.

Comment: You answered your own question.

Comment: I know it's a proper name, but etymogically, what does zhōngxing means? Xiexie.

Comment: I saw others' answers. They might be true. But that's just a name, only the brand owner can officially explain it.

Comment: @Shiji.Jiang Ah, I see.... Thanks for your feedback! ;) ;) ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

中興 as a single term, does mean "revival, restoration" particularly refers to a period of revival of a declining dynasty.

*中興 is mostly a history text book term, when we are talking about a particular period in history. It is never used in contemporary sense. People who were living in a 中興 period would not refer their country's revival as a temporary state*

However as a company name in this case, we have to see 中 and 興 as individual characters because China is not in decline. and 中 clearly refers to 中國 (China), not 中期(middle period)

中 stands for: 中國 = China

興 means: "thriving; prosperous; flourishing" as in "興盛" (thrive,flourish)

中興通訊 means "Flourishing China Communication "

Comment: Thanks, man... Very accurate and informed answer! Please reply always for my questions. :))) :d

Comment: @FarnzSeager Are you sure? I think 中 means China since centuries ago!

Comment: @FarnzSeager Thanks for your reply! So if that中 didn't mean China, what did it mean? ;)

Comment: 中 contains meanings of : " (adj)middle;  center; inside; medium; average; halfway; (v)directly hit " - Now try to add Flourishing to any of the meanings I listed. "Flourishing Middle, Medium flourish, Halfway flourish? " My conclusion is still "China is the obvious choice."

Answer (score 6):

> 中兴通讯的前身是1985年由航天系统的691厂以及运兴香港电子等共同投资创办的“中兴半导体”。而“中兴”名字由来有二：一是因为691厂是中方企业，港资企业为运兴，各取一字，成为“中兴”；第二个更为重要的原因是“中兴”暗含中国兴旺的意思。这也正表达了当时创业者侯为贵寄望中兴通讯振兴民族通信产业的理想。后来，中兴通讯称谓先后经历了中兴维先通、中兴新的变化，但始终坚持“中兴”二字。如今，“中兴通讯，中国兴旺”已写入中兴通讯企业文化的第一条。

Source: [ZTE official site](http://www.zte.com.cn/Events/zte30years/media/messager_15.htm)

If you cannot read Chinese, you may refer to the following translations in my poor English:

There are two reasons why this company is called [中兴]:

1. ZTE is combined by two corporations: 中国航天691厂(CASC 691 Factory, a Chinese company) and 兴运 (Xing1 Yun4, a Hong Kong company). take one word from each company, we get[中] and [兴].
2. Like other users said, 中兴=中国兴盛=China's soaring.